# Split string by whitespace, difference

Tags: string, split, whitespace, difference

What is the difference between `Regex.Split(Console.ReadLine(), @"\s+");` and `Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 0):

The regex version will split by any whitespace character (for instance, including tabs), while the other one only splits by space characters.

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx) (which annoyingly doesn't support anchor links, so scroll down to "White-Space Character: \s") has a listing of what characters are considered "whitespace".

Comment: `Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[]{' ','\t'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` still don't work for me

Comment: @Matheus: So how about you describe how it's "not working" in your question? You didn't see anything about that.